# what is the way to give fix width for table cells which works in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I need to give a fix width for a table cell. css things not works, hope a immediate answer

Comment: Post the code, especially if you need a quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

Specify a direct width for the table, as well as set the table-layout to fixed:

```
table#myTable{
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 726px;
}
```

Comment: I am creating a dynamic table, so i cant give fix table size. this is not working in my issue.

Comment: @Dinidu Just leave the `width` out of the rule, and fix the widths for the `TD`s dynamically (which you probably do already).

Answer (score 0):

Yes I found a way to over come this, you can use "nowrap" tag for that

syntax:- `<td nowrap="nowrap">  </td>`